# `pyspark mllib` versus `pyspark ml` packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

What is difference between `pyspark mllib` and `pyspark ml` packages ? :

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html

`pyspark mllib` appears to be target algorithms at dataframe level `pyspark ml`

One difference I found is `pyspark ml` implements `pyspark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator` while `pyspark mllib` does not.

My understanding is the library should use if implementing algorithms on Apache Spark framework is `mllib` but there appears to be a split ?

There does not appear to be interoperability between each of the frameworks without transforming types as they each contain a different package structure.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From my experience `pyspark.mllib` classes can only be used with `pyspark.RDD`'s, whereas (as you mention) `pyspark.ml` classes can only be used with `pyspark.sql.DataFrame`'s. There is mention to support this in the documentation for `pyspark.ml`, the first entry in [`pyspark.ml package`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html) states:

> DataFrame-based machine learning APIs to let users quickly assemble and configure practical machine learning pipelines.

Now I am reminded of an article I read a while back regarding the three API's available in Spark 2.0, their relative benefits/drawbacks and their comparative performance. [A Tale of Three Apache Spark APIs: RDDs, DataFrames, and Datasets](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html). I was in the midst of doing performance testing on new client servers and was interested if there would ever be a scenario in which it would be worth developing an RDD based approach as opposed to a DataFrame based approach (my approach of choice), but I digress.

The gist was that there are situations in which each are highly suited and others where they might not be. One example I remember is that if you data is already structured DataFrames confer some performance benefits over RDD's, this is apparently drastic as the complexity of your operations increase. Another observation was that DataSets and DataFrames consume far less memory when caching than RDD's. In summation the author concluded that for low level operations RDD's are great, but for high level operations, viewing, and tying with other API's DataFrames and DataSets are superior.

So to come back full circle to your question, I believe the answer is a resounding `pyspark.ml` as the classes in this package are designed to utilize `pyspark.sql.DataFrames`. I would imagine that the performance of complex algorithms implemented in each of these packages would be significant if you were to test against the same data structured as a DataFrame vs RDD. Furthermore, viewing the data and developing compelling visuals would be both more intuitive and have better performance.

Comment: +1 , in my experience implementing at RDD level faster than at dataframe level in terms of algorithm implementation but I'm biased towards  preferring functional (rdd) rather than sql (dataframe) styles.

Comment: The book Spark 2 The Definitive Guide... validates this answer and, in fact, encourages use of the DataFrame centric, newer MLib. In fact, I believe it said that the older MLlib is now in maintenance status, and will only receive fixes. Sadly, I don't have a link to the book for you (as I type this from a small phone), but it's the latest one from O'Reilly.